Is there a way to store managed pointers in a stackalloc buffer without incurring unexpected behavior from the GC?
I'm working with C# in a game engine and frequently need to pass around subsets of collections of objects to different synchronous functions. I need to avoid making heap allocations for each call, and have investigated a few solutions. One that seemed elegant conceptually was to stackalloc a buffer and store references to the objects in it, then pass that buffer as a Span to whatever function I needed to call.
However, I know the docs state that stackalloc can only be used with unmanaged types. I've read a few descriptions of why this is the case, including this SO answer. My limited understanding is that the garbage collector needs to track all of the potential references to objects for the purposes of moving and freeing them. But stackalloc creates a value type with no fields, just a raw blob of memory with no type info, so the GC inherently can't know anything about it.
Through use of the Unsafe and MemoryMarshal classes, I've written a workaround that allocates and reinterprets a buffer on the stack:
IntPtr* ptr = stackalloc IntPtr[count];
ref T tRef = ref Unsafe.AsRef<T>(ptr); // T is some object
Span<T> buff = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref tRef, count);
... // Copy references into buff and pass it to some function

This works as expected so far. However, I haven't used this solution extensively yet and don't know if there will be any unexpected behavior over sustained GC runs.
I know the objects won't be freed as they're still referenced by the original heap allocated collections. But I want to ensure the objects won't be moved by the GC while calling a function with these stack buffers. Is this possible?
Will the GC account for the references stored in this memory because it's now being pointed to by a Span? If not, is it possible to avoid the referenced objects from being moved using the Span with the fixed statement and pinning them? If that won't work, is there any other way to ensure they won't be moved for the duration of the function call, or is this just not possible whatsoever?
edit:
I asked this question in a discussion on the dotnet runtime repo. After some suggestions and testing, using stackalloc in this way can be done safely if the objects whose references are being stored are pinned in memory. While this works, the additional overhead of pinning was a significant cost that makes this impractical for any real use.

This is dangerous, it creates a GC "hole" where the pointers are not being tracked. Why do you need to actually copy the references around, rather than just passing the offsets into the array as a stackalloc Span? Also you can assign stackalloc to a Span<IntPtr> directly, no need for IntPtr*.

@Charlieface That's a backup option I'm considering. But I wanted to understand what happens in this case and if there were ways to utilize it safely, such as if pinning the objects before using them would prevent any problems.
For the 2nd question, that ends up requiring an additional library call to create the reinterpreted Span. Though when writing helper functions, I did actually write it using a Span just because I think the improved readability is worth the minor additional overhead. I just think this example better portrays what I'm doing for the sake of the question.

The answer you linked explains why this is a problem: it's not tracked by GC properly. Yes it may work, but it can also fail catastrophically and in unexpected ways. The references themselves will be tracked once in the span, but the span itself won't be tracked.

@Charlieface are you sure all references in the span will be tracked (updated references)? if not pinned that is.

@IvanPetrov I think so, because the Unsafe.As returns a Span of T which should be tracked once it returns, it's just the span itself that's the concern, as the GC has lost track of the stackalloc pointer. It might be safe, but I wouldn't rely on it without a definitvive judgement from the team on https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

@Charlieface It explains the underlying mechanics of stackalloc, but is a bit old and the CLR has expanded since then, such as the addition of Span. I wanted to know if there were currently any features of the language that can be used to safely accomplish this narrow use case. Also, regarding the Span, I don't need believe I need it to be tracked. After the call is complete I'd be discarding the references and deallocating the memory, and all of the functions where this would be used are synchronous.

Like I said, I'd suggest filing an issue on Github asking if this is a reasonable workaround. It's very hard to know if doing something apparently unsafe like that is actually safe, without having a lot of internal knowledge of the runtime, and even then it's probably subject to change without notice.

@Charlieface That's a good idea. I didn't know if there was a place to ask those kinds of questions, but I see now there's a discussion tab which I think would be an appropriate place to ask. Thank you

OK so if that comes up with anything definitive then we can reopen this. Anyway, you can avoid unsafe context by using MemoryMarshal.GetReference https://dotnetfiddle.net/UFthah

@Charlieface Span<T> is just a struct with a managed pointer that points to a T. A single T. GC will update pointers in ref managed pointers on the stack for single variables, but I really doubt it that the GC will consider the length property of Span<T> and treat everything inside as ref variables...

@Charlieface MemoryMarshal.GetReference does work but also requires an additional step of calling Unsafe.As to reinterpret the ref IntPtr to a ref T, whereas using the stackalloc pointer directly just needs a single call to Unsafe.AsRef. Not really a big deal though, and I do think keeping everything in Spans is a bit more readable. https://dotnetfiddle.net/7wmGB4

@Lich check my updated answer...I think that's the solution if you are on. NET8


I am explicitly attempting to avoid allocating a new heap array for
each call I make.

For your purposes, there seems to be a built-in solution - ArrayPool<T>:

Using the ArrayPool class to rent and return buffers (using the
Rent and Return methods) can improve performance in situations where
arrays are created and destroyed frequently, resulting in significant
memory pressure on the garbage collector.

An alternative is a new feature in .NET 8 - Inline Arrays:
[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InlineArray(10)]
public struct Buffer
{
    private object _element0;
}


Runtime provides regular GC tracking for all elements in the struct.

Since this is a struct it will be on the stack and no allocations would be done. You can read the docs for using a Span<T> as a wrapper. The fact that you have to predefine the size of the buffer might not be an issue since you said that the count is

usually in the single to low double-digits

so you can have a count of 15-20 and then have the Span slice over the real count.

This does solve the underlying goal I need to achieve and is something I'm considering, although this specific question was more about if it was possible to use the stack buffer safely. I think my original question didn't convey that well enough, so I've edited it to try and make it more clear.

that's the way to achieve what you wanted. Since you didn't mention why it won't work for you in the original question, I thought you weren't aware of it and went for crazier alternatives
